# What is the alternative to display upload preview image other than base64

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs-directive

What is the alternative to displaying the upload preview other than base64 so that it doesn't become heavy when the link is opened like facebook, I have 2 examples found between AngularJS and Javacript?

```
AngularJS https://jsfiddle.net/BimoSora/s0ckjqp3/5/

  .directive("fileinput", [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        fileinput: "=",
        filepreview: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, element, attributes) {
        element.bind("change", function(changeEvent) {
          scope.fileinput = changeEvent.target.files[0];
          var reader = new FileReader();
          reader.onload = function(loadEvent) {
            scope.$apply(function() {
              scope.filepreview = loadEvent.target.result;
            });
          }
          reader.readAsDataURL(scope.fileinput);
        });
      }
    }
  }]);
```

```
Javacript https://codepen.io/mrtokachh/pen/LYGvPBj

function ImgUpload() {
  var imgWrap = "";
  var imgArray = [];

  $('.upload__inputfile').each(function () {
    $(this).on('change', function (e) {
      imgWrap = $(this).closest('.upload__box').find('.upload__img-wrap');
      var maxLength = $(this).attr('data-max_length');

      var files = e.target.files;
      var filesArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(files);
      var iterator = 0;
      filesArr.forEach(function (f, index) {

        if (!f.type.match('image.*')) {
          return;
        }

        if (imgArray.length > maxLength) {
          return false
        } else {
          var len = 0;
          for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
            if (imgArray[i] !== undefined) {
              len++;
            }
          }
          if (len > maxLength) {
            return false;
          } else {
            imgArray.push(f);

            var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function (e) {
              var html = "<div class='upload__img-box'><div style='background-image: url(" + e.target.result + ")' data-number='" + $(".upload__img-close").length + "' data-file='" + f.name + "' class='img-bg'><div class='upload__img-close'></div></div></div>";
              imgWrap.append(html);
              iterator++;
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

  $('body').on('click', ".upload__img-close", function (e) {
    var file = $(this).parent().data("file");
    for (var i = 0; i < imgArray.length; i++) {
      if (imgArray[i].name === file) {
        imgArray.splice(i, 1);
        break;
      }
    }
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
  });
}
```

Why is base64 the most sought after for preview uploads even though it is very difficult to open the link?

Comment: What is your exact problem to solve? If you upload an image you need to convert it to show. And the easiest way is to use base64